# Boolean arithmetics in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a set of pl/sql functions, all returning a boolean type.
I call these function from another pl/sql function one by one. I want to "accumulate" the results and return it from that function.

For example:

```
  v_res  boolean;
  v_res2 boolean := true;
begin
  v_res := f1('aa');
  if v_res = false then
    v_res2 := false;
  end if;

  v_res := f2('aa');
  if v_res = false then
    v_res2 := false;
  end if;

  -- some other calls to other functions

  return v_res2;
end;
```

I was wondering, can I do boolean arithmetic in pl/sql ?
I mean something like this:

```
  v_res boolean := true;
begin
  v_res := v_res * f1('aa');
  v_res := v_res * f2('aa');
  -- more calls to functions
  return v_res;
end;
```

I tried:

```
v_res := v_res * false;
```

and

```
v_res := v_res and false;
```

but the only thing that seems to work was converting the boolean to an int (I tried with sys.diutil.bool_to_int) which doesn't feel right ...

Comment: `v_res * false` - what do you expect as a result of such odd expression?

Comment: Your last attempt works: `v_res := v_res and f1('aa');`

Comment: @TonyAndrews, You're absolutely right! I have no idea what happened last time I checked ...

Comment: @zerkms, I would expect it to be false as in "C".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
begin
  return f1('aa')
     and f2('aa')
     ... etc. ...
     ;
end;
```